LWC Embedded in Aura Component to dispatch Events on Close Browser tab or Window
Hi I've been working with platform events in LWC, and I need to monitor user activity on an specific object record page.
It works well but I had to do kind of a ping system between the LWC insances on each record page and that has brought me to fight with Platform Event Daily Delivery Limits.
So doing some research came to find about lighning:unsavedchanges, but Im not sure if this have a way to automatically publish an event from an aura component when the user close the browser tab or window where the aura component is hosted. Is it possible?
Do you guys by any chance have any example?
